# Regarding the "set!" and "let" expressions

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have got this small program defined in a file `a.scm`:

```
(define f
  (let ((x 0))
    (lambda ()
      (set! x (+ 1 x))
      x)))
```

Upon calling `f` repeatedly, the result keeps on increasing:

```
CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2016, The CHICKEN Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.11.0
linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
compiled 2016-08-23 on buildvm-13.phx2.fedoraproject.org

#;1> (load "a.scm")
; loading a.scm ...
#;2> (f)
1
#;3> (f)
2
#;4> (f)
3
#;5>
```

Could someone please throw some light as to why `x` is bound to `0` only the first time `f` is invoked? I expect that every time `f` is invoked, the `let` binding should get executed.

Also, if on repeated invocations, `x` is not bound to `0` then how does the lambda expression get to know that `x` is a  'free variable' within it's body (instead of returning an error like 'variable not bound` or something)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone please throw some light as to why x is bound to 0 only the first time f is invoked?

`x` is bound to 0 ***not*** when `f` is *invoked*, but when it is *created*.

Let me rewrite your function in Common Lisp:

```
(let ((x 0))
  (defun f ()
    (incf x)))
(f)
==> 1
(f)
==> 2
(f)
==> 3
(f)
==> 4
```

`f` is a closure over the variable `x`.

IOW, when `f` is created, `x` is bound to 0 and made available in `f` - and *only* in `f`.

Answer (score 1):

The `let` is not inside the function's body; the `let` is evaluated when `f` is defined, not when it's called.

The function's body is `(set! x (+ 1 x)) x)`, where `x` refers to the variable defined by the `let`.
Or to put another way, `f` is not bound to the `let` but to the `lambda`.

Similarly,

```
(define x (let ((y 12)) y))
```

binds `x` to `12`, not to `(let ((y 12)) y)`.

Answer (score 0):

I understood `set!` as 'binding a value to a symbol directly in the constant environment', which means that the symbol (here `x`) isn't available to bindings (such as let or a function parameter) anymore.

The only procedure that can override this 'binding to a symbol' is another `set!` . So, when you call your function over and over again, it looks up the symbol `x` and does a new 'set!'. If you reload your file new, this binding should be reset. Does it?

btw...did someone say CHICKEN ?

Comment: `set!` does not bind anything: it mutates an existing binding.  If there is no existing binding then its behaviour is not defined (in fact, may well be an error: I am not familiar enough with the Scheme standard to say).  The abuse of `set!`, or `setf` / `setq'` in CL, to create bindings is usually a symptom of Python-induced braindamage.

Comment: You are right - i was indeed thinking about something else. Not Python though.